# Почему когда я удаляю файлы через PHPStorm (слева вверху есть дерево файлов), они не появляются в корзине? Как сделать чтобы появлялись?

Tags: phpstorm

Почему когда я удаляю файлы через PHPStorm (слева вверху есть дерево файлов), они не появляются в корзине? Как сделать чтобы появлялись?

[image]

Comment: Когда нажимаешь на Delete... появляется диалоговое окно. Что в нем написано?

Comment: Кстати, для чего нужно, чтобы файлы появлялись в корзине?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpStorm не умеет удалять файлы в корзину, поскольку эта функция не поддерживается java машиной. Соответствующая функциональность доступна только начиная с 9 версии java (https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4641147), а PhpStorm работает с 1.8.

Для восстановления удаленных файлов можно использовать [Local history](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/local-history.html)

Answer (score 2):

В phpstorm есть своя "корзина". Это local history. Правой кнопкой на дереве файлов: local history - show history. Там будут и удаленные файлы и история изменений всех файлов.